# How can I wrap black-boxed, asynchronous calls in a synchronous manner?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization

I am using a proprietary, 3rd party framework in my Android app -- EMDK from Zebra, to be specific -- and two of their exposed methods:

`.read()` and `.cancelRead()` are asynchronous, each taking anywhere from a split second to a 5 whole seconds to complete. I need to be able to spam them without crashing my application and ensure that each one isn't called twice in a row. How can I go about doing this? I don't have any access to the methods themselves and a decompiler will only give me runtime stubs.

Edit: I also have no idea when each of these two calls ever completes.

Answer (score 1):

Changing asynchronous programs into blocking ones is a more general requirement to this problem.

In Java, we can do this with `CountDownLatch` (as well as `Phaser`), or `LockSupport + Atomic`.

For example, if it is required to change an asynchronous call `asyncDoSomethingAwesome(param, callback)` into a blocking one, we could write a "wrapper" method like this:

```
ResultType doSomethingAwesome(ParamType param) {
    AtomicReference<ResultType> resultContainer = new AtomicReference<>();
    Thread callingThread = Thread.currentThread();
    asyncDoSomethingAwesome(param, result -> {
        resultContainer.set(result);
        LockSupport.unpark(callingThread);
    });
    ResultType result;
    while ((result = resultContainer.get()) == null) {
        LockSupport.park();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I think this will be enough to solve your problem. However, when we are writing blocking programs, we usually want a "timeout" to keep the system stable even when an underlying interface is not working properly, for example:

```
ResultType doSomethingAwesome(ParamType param, Duration timeout) throws TimeoutException {
    AtomicReference<ResultType> resultContainer = new AtomicReference<>();
    Thread callingThread = Thread.currentThread();
    asyncDoSomethingAwesome(param, result -> {
        resultContainer.set(result);
        LockSupport.unpark(callingThread);
    });
    ResultType result;
    long deadline = Instant.now().plus(timeout).toEpochMilli();
    while ((result = resultContainer.get()) == null) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= deadline) {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        LockSupport.parkUntil(deadline);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sometimes we need more refined management to the signal among threads, especially when writing concurrency libries. For example, when we need to know whether the blocking thread received the signal from another thread calling `LockSupport.unpark`, or whether that thread successfully notified the blocking thread, it is usually not easy to implement with Java standard library. Thus I designed another library with more complete mechanism to solve this issue: 
https://github.com/wmx16835/experimental_java_common/blob/master/alpha/src/main/java/mingxin/wang/common/concurrent/DisposableBlocker.java

With the support of `DisposableBlocker`, life will become much easier :)

```
ResultType doSomethingAwesome(ParamType param, Duration timeout) throws TimeoutException {
    // We can use org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableObject instead of AtomicReference,
    // because this object will never be accessed concurrently
    MutableObject<ResultType> resultContainer = new MutableObject<>();
    DisposableBlocker blocker = new DisposableBlocker();
    asyncDoSomethingAwesome(param, result -> {
        resultContainer.setValue(result);
        blocker.unblock();
    });
    if (!blocker.blockFor(timeout)) {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
    return resultContainer.getValue();
}
```

Comment: What if `asyncDoSomethingAwesome` is black-boxed and returns `void`? I have no idea when my async methods finish and I am unable to edit them, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was -- what if `asyncDoSomethingAwesome` has no callback?

Comment: If the async API does not support callback, and we are not able to redesign it, the only way to get notified is to query the result repeatedly (usually with a certain interval). However, as far as I know, this approach is usually not recommended on stand-alone system for its inefficiency and complexity. If we are able to resedign the API and allow it to accept a callback, things will be much easier. @grant-park

Answer (score 0):

Might be off on this as I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve/nor the structure, but could you wrap each in an AsyncTask? Then in a parent AsyncTask or background thread:

```
AsyncTask1.execute().get(); //get will block until complete
AsyncTask2.execute().get(); //get will block until complete
```

This is assuming there is some way of knowing the calls you're making completed.

Comment: I have no idea when they complete, unfortunately. Also, I can achieve what you did via using a semaphore too, but there still aren't guarantees that one of the methods won't be called twice.

Comment: Gotchya. Just looked at the documentation... without knowing anything, is it possible to block from isReadPending() - sounds like the only way to tell if a read() is being ran?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the documentation -- unfortunately, it isn't reliable for a number of reasons outside the scope of my question. EMDK seems to be riddled with inconsistencies and I'd really like to find a way to guard rail some of them. Handling async properly is a first step :)